# How to update a field at index in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  function updateFAQ(e, id) {
    let newFAQList = [...faqDesc];
    console.log(e.target.value);

    newFAQList[id].question = e.target.value;
    //newFAQList[id].answer = e.target.value;
    setfaq(newFAQList);
  }
```

```
function EditFAQ(props) {
  return (
    <form>
      <TextField
        name="question"
        onChange={e => props.onChange(e, props.id)}
        value={props.question}
      ></TextField>
      <Divider />
      <TextField
       name="answer"
        value={props.answer}
        onChange={e => props.onChange(e, props.id)}
      ></TextField>
      <button> Save Edit </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

```
  {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "question",
        "answer": "answer"
    },
```

into

```
  {
        "id": 4,
        "question": "changed question",
        "answer": "answer changed"
    },
```

How would I update the faq for question and answer at a given index? I plan on having a form to update the FAQ list at the given index. I would want to update something like the example but i tried using e.target.name to get the field and put it next to newFAQList[id].e.target.name= e.target.value but does not work

Comment: What is your input and expected output? Also you seem to be doing this already, are you looking for perhaps an immutable way of doing it?

Comment: updated the question. Trying to update fields wtih e.target.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function updateFAQ(e, id) {
    setfaqDesc(
      faqDesc.map(faq =>
        faq.id === id ? { ...faq, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } : faq
      )
    );
  }
```

this would set the target name to the target value onChange

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some `arrayLst` with data and you can do something like this:

```
function updateFAQ( value, desc ) {
  for (var i in arrayLst) {
   if (arrayLst[i].value == value) { // i -> index
     arrayLst[i].desc = desc; // add whatever you want to do.        
  }
 }
}
```

**OR**

```js
//let your array be
let arrayLst = [
  {id: 0, name: "Roy"},
  {id: 1, name: "John"},
  {id: 2, name: "Doe"},
  {id: 3, name: "Angela"}
],
    
//Find index of specific object using findIndex method.    
index= arrayLst.findIndex((obj => obj.id == 1));
console.log("Before update: ", arrayLst[index])
arrayLst[index].name = "Paul" //John to Paul
console.log("After update: ", arrayLst[index])
```

Comment: lets say theres a last name field. I plan on having an update form. How would i update the name and last name at a given index?